# Can I define a global across jobs

Tags: github-actions

I have a workflow with 2 jobs:

```
on: [push]

jobs:
  ssql:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
### bunch of steps in between ###
  - name: Upload data as artifact
    uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
    with:
      name: ${{ env.GAME }} + "-" + "data"
      path: output_data/training-data.csv
    env:
      GAME: "FunGame"

Rtrain:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Train model
    needs: ssql
    steps:
      - name: checkout current repo
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Retreive data from ssql job 
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: ${{ env.GAME }} + "-" + "data"
        env:
          GAME: "FunGame"
```

I had to set env variable $GAME twice, once in each job. Is there any syntax where I can e.g. add this at the top to make it truly global across jobs, e.g. something like:

```
on: [push]

env:
  GAME: "FunGame"

jobs: ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set an env variable exactly as you described at the workflow level.

Just note that it can conflict with env variables set at the job level, or at the step level, if they have the same name. In that case, the variable used is the most specific one: `STEP` over `JOB` over `WORKFLOW`.

[Reference 1](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-server@2.22/actions/reference/environment-variables) + [Reference 2](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-server@2.22/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#env)

Here is an example of how to use env variables at different levels (without conflict):

```yaml
name: Environment Workflow

on:
  workflow_dispatch:

env:
  WORKFLOW_VARIABLE: WORKFLOW

jobs:

  job1:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      JOB_VARIABLE: JOB
    steps:
      - name: Run Commands with various variables
        if: ${{ env.WORKFLOW_VARIABLE == 'WORKFLOW' }}
        env:
          STEP_VARIABLE: STEP
        run: |
          echo "Hello World"
          echo "This is the $WORKFLOW_VARIABLE environment variable"
          echo "This is the $JOB_VARIABLE environment variable"
          echo "This is the $STEP_VARIABLE environment variable"
```

- [Full workflow implementation (if you want to reproduce)](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/blob/main/.github/workflows/10-environment-workflow.yml)
- [Previous workflow run display](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/actions/runs/1252774840)